# What will git add if I add this directory?

Tags: git

A situation that has arisen a few times now:

I have a directory full of files, `foo/`, not yet added to version control. `git status` agrees that this is so. I'm about to type `git add foo`, but wait, there are some binaries in there that should not be added to version control. Hopefully they are successfully being `.gitignore`d, but I'm not sure, and I don't want to find out after the fact, because it's a nuisance having to expunge things from version control after they've been added.

Is there a way I can ask git 'if I were to tell you to add `foo/`, what specific files in it would you add?'

Comment: You mean like the dry-run option?

Comment: @DaveNewton it turns out I mean exactly like that, thank you!

Comment: `git add` has the option for dry-run, `--dry-run` or `-n`.

Answer (score 2):

To do this *before* adding the files:

```
git status -uall
```

or if you like the more verbose spelling:

```
git status --untracked-files=all
```

This will list all the files that Git sees as untracked, minus any files that are untracked but suppressed via a `.gitignore`.  Add any missing names or patterns to the appropriate `.gitignore` (creating `foo/.gitignore` first if desired / needed).

---

*After* adding the files, if there are some that are now tracked that should not be, they will show up as new files in `git status`.  Use `git rm --cached` on each such file,<sup>1</sup> and add the appropriate name or file-name-pattern to an appropriate `.gitignore` so that a future `git add foo` can do the right thing.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can also use `git reset` on each such file, as in [Nizar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59795844/1256452).

Comment: Yeah that's the perfect answer. It is nice to know about `-uall`. That'll come in handy! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have them in `.gitignore` you have nothing to worry about.

You can go ahead and do the following

```
git add foo
git status
```

This will list all the files that have been added. You can `grep` them if you want. If you see a file in there that you don't want, you can just `unstage` them, by doing the following:

```
git reset foo/*
```

Comment: It is probably not a good option since you have `.gitignore` dedicated to this functionality.

Comment: @ParthS007 You will have to add the contents of the directory anyway in order to commit them, `.gitignore` is there so you won't have to `unstage` the files because they won't be added anyway.

Answer (score 1):

yet another option is to use `git add --interactive` to step through adding of each file

this will lead you through a prompt which will ask you to add each of the files that you specified

```
$ git add --interactive foo

*** Commands ***
  1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked
  5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8: help
What now> 4
  1: foo/a
  2: foo/b
  3: foo/c
Add untracked>> 1
* 1: foo/a
  2: foo/b
  3: foo/c
Add untracked>> 2
* 1: foo/a
* 2: foo/b
  3: foo/c
Add untracked>> 3
* 1: foo/a
* 2: foo/b
* 3: foo/c
Add untracked>>
added 3 paths

*** Commands ***
  1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked
  5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8: help
What now> q
Bye.

$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   foo/a
        new file:   foo/b
        new file:   foo/c
```

Answer (score 0):

If git is showing `foo/` as an untracked folder, It will add all of it to staging.

It depends on the project `.gitignore` what will be added on staging.